# Python : Splitting a value into two and assigning into two different variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, iterable-unpacking

I am trying to get a string from a file that has a start and end date range as below:

```
"Date Range = January 1, 2001 to December 24, 2008"
```

I have to pick this date range (January 1, 2001 to December 24, 2008) and split it and assign it into 2 different variables. I am able to fetch the date range and split them, but when assigning I get an error.

```
file_path = open("C:\\Users\\vinnu\\Desktop\\ARF_LS00006493_339313_Tremont.txt")
content = file_path.read()

#find and pick the date range
size = len(content)
start =0
while start < size:
    start = content.find("Date Range: ",start)
    start = start if start != -1 else size
    #fetch only till the end of line
    end = content.find("\n", start)
    end = end if end != -1 else size
    date_range = (content[start+12:end])
    start = end + 1
    #printing test
    print (date_range)

    #split
    date1,date2= date_range.split(' to ')
    print (date1)
    print (date2)
```

I get the below output with an error:

```
January 1, 2001 to December 24, 2008
January 1, 2001
December 24, 2008

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vinnu/Desktop/split_eg3.py", line 19, in <module>
    date1,date2= date_range.split(' to ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: I would suggest to save the return value from split in one variable (thereby saving the whole list of return values) and printing that out to check what values you get. looks to me like you don't get 2 return values from the split function, only 1

Comment: That's weird; I can't reproduce your error; the code looks fine to me. Are you sure there isn't something else?

Comment: It seems like error appears on the second iteration of your while loop, so problem might be in another place.

Comment: Are all the lines in your file of the form "Date range = <Start Time> to <End Time>"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain the output you are getting

First time in the loop, all is good...

```
January 1, 2001 to December 24, 2008
January 1, 2001
December 24, 2008
```

Now you are entering the loop again (most likely you have some \n\n in the file at the end of it)

```
start = content.find("Date Range: ",start)
start = start if start != -1 else size
```

start should "size" now

```
date_range = (content[start+12:end]) # start==size remember? => ""
start = end + 1
#printing test
print (date_range) #you print an empty string here!
```

After printing the empty line

```
date1,date2= date_range.split(' to ') #splitting the empty string
```

and exploding:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vinnu/Desktop/split_eg3.py", line 19, in <module>
    date1,date2= date_range.split(' to ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: gosh.... got it now..! thank you yoav galzner. and all others who had some time to help me...!

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a loop for this, you can use split for the whole process:

```
def parseDates(s):
    _, dates = s.split(" = ")
    initDate, endDate = dates.split(" to ")
    return (initDate, endDate)
```

Then use the function while reading your file:

```
with open("yourFileName", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        id, ed = parseDates(line)
        print(id)
        print(ed)
```